# How to specify Multiple schema's of Mysql in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am working with two schema's in mysql for spring boot application. If i use single schema i can specify the schema name as mentioned below.

```
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/holmes_kyc_config
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Drive
```

Now i am using two schema's So i tried to give schema name in the bean class it self,instead of give in application.properties as like below.

This is one Bean class; @Entity @Table(name = "user_auth",schema = "holmes_kyc_config") public class UserAuthentication {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "iduser_auth")
private Integer iduser_auth;
```

This is second Bean class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_auth",schema = "kyc_user_schema")
public class PhaseStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idnew_table")
    private Integer idnew_table;
```

So could you please guide me what's the correct way to give two schema's.

Comment: Please explain the encountered issue with your try.

Comment: @davidxxx Getting error like  "java.sql.SQLException: No database selected"